# How remove the label data from feature data from window time series (tensorflow)

Tags: pandas, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I train a models of time series forecasting use tensorflow. The models in this tutorial will make a set of predictions based on a window of consecutive samples from the data.
[image]

## *I want to remove the label data from feature data in this function

## *

d

```
ef split_window(self, features):
  inputs = features[:, self.input_slice, :]
  labels = features[:, self.labels_slice, :]
  if self.label_columns is not None:
    labels = tf.stack(
        [labels[:, :, self.column_indices[name]] for name in self.label_columns],
        axis=-1)

  # Slicing doesn't preserve static shape information, so set the shapes
  # manually. This way the `tf.data.Datasets` are easier to inspect.
  inputs.set_shape([None, self.input_width, None])
  labels.set_shape([None, self.label_width, None])

  return inputs, labels


WindowGenerator.split_window = split_window
```

## This the whole code of windwing

```
class WindowGenerator():
  def __init__(self, input_width, label_width, shift,
               train_df=train_df, val_df=val_df, test_df=test_df,
               label_columns=None):
    # Store the raw data.
    self.train_df = train_df
    self.val_df = val_df
    self.test_df = test_df

    # Work out the label column indices.
    self.label_columns = label_columns
    if label_columns is not None:
      self.label_columns_indices = {name: i for i, name in
                                    enumerate(label_columns)}
    self.column_indices = {name: i for i, name in
                           enumerate(train_df.columns)}

    # Work out the window parameters.
    self.input_width = input_width
    self.label_width = label_width
    self.shift = shift

    self.total_window_size = input_width + shift

    self.input_slice = slice(0, input_width)
    self.input_indices = np.arange(self.total_window_size)[self.input_slice]

    self.label_start = self.total_window_size - self.label_width
    self.labels_slice = slice(self.label_start, None)
    self.label_indices = np.arange(self.total_window_size)[self.labels_slice]

  def __repr__(self):
    return '\n'.join([
        f'Total window size: {self.total_window_size}',
        f'Input indices: {self.input_indices}',
        f'Label indices: {self.label_indices}',
        f'Label column name(s): {self.label_columns}'])


def split_window(self, features):
  inputs = features[:, self.input_slice, :]
  labels = features[:, self.labels_slice, :]
  if self.label_columns is not None:
    labels = tf.stack(
        [labels[:, :, self.column_indices[name]] for name in self.label_columns],
        axis=-1)

  # Slicing doesn't preserve static shape information, so set the shapes
  # manually. This way the `tf.data.Datasets` are easier to inspect.
  inputs.set_shape([None, self.input_width, None])
  labels.set_shape([None, self.label_width, None])

  return inputs, labels


WindowGenerator.split_window = split_window

def make_dataset(self, data):
  data = np.array(data, dtype=np.float32)
  ds = tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
      data=data,
      targets=None,
      sequence_length=self.total_window_size,
      sequence_stride=1,
      shuffle=True,
      batch_size=32,)

  ds = ds.map(self.split_window)

  return ds


WindowGenerator.make_dataset = make_dataset

@property
def train(self):
  return self.make_dataset(self.train_df)


@property
def val(self):
  return self.make_dataset(self.val_df)


@property
def test(self):
  return self.make_dataset(self.test_df)


@property
def example(self):
  """Get and cache an example batch of `inputs, labels` for plotting."""
  result = getattr(self, '_example', None)
  if result is None:
    # No example batch was found, so get one from the `.train` dataset
    result = next(iter(self.train))
    # And cache it for next time
    self._example = result
  return result


WindowGenerator.train = train
WindowGenerator.val = val
WindowGenerator.test = test
WindowGenerator.example = example
```

This code from https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#baseline

## *I want to remove the label data from feature data

if the data is [col1, col2, col3, col4]
I want
label data is [col4]
feature data id [col1, col2, col3]

Answer (score 0):

```
def split_window(self, features):
  inputs = features[:, self.input_slice, :]
  labels = features[:, self.labels_slice, :]
  inputs_col = [#col names]
  
  inputs = tf.stack([inputs[:, :, self.column_indices[name]] for name in inputs_col],axis=-1)
    
  if self.label_columns is not None:
    labels = tf.stack(
        [labels[:, :, self.column_indices[name]] for name in self.label_columns],
        axis=-1)

  # Slicing doesn't preserve static shape information, so set the shapes
  # manually. This way the `tf.data.Datasets` are easier to inspect.
  inputs.set_shape([None, self.input_width, None])
  labels.set_shape([None, self.label_width, None])

  return inputs, labels


WindowGenerator.split_window = split_window
```

Comment: This the solution

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).